# Create an array of objects from mongoose database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have some users in the mongodb/mongoose database and I want to put all their names of people in the same zip code into an array.

```
var namesArray = [];

Users.find({ zip: '55555' }, function ( err, people ) {
  for ( i = 0, i < people.length, i++ ) {
    namesArray[i] = people.name // How do I specify which person to use if they're all being returned at once?
  };
});
```

Comment: "people" will already be returned as array from the "find" method.  You can do with it as you like.  Check out `.forEach`

Comment: I love you. I wish I could give you upvote points. I'm trying to upvote your comment.

Comment: You'll want to access an index of `people` in the same way you're already doing with `namesArray` -- `namesArray[i] = people[i].name;`

Comment: Also, with the structure of your snippet, for a possible future question: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 var namesArray=[];
Users.find({ zip: '55555' }, function ( err, people ) {
  for ( i in people) {
    namesArray[i] = people[i]
  };
});
```